# Power BI empty dimension values show only in total

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix struggle when a dimension is empty but it must have to be empty.

This is my product hierarchy (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwDfJ.png)

That means that only the main products have the full category dimensions. The Complementary products compatible with more than one main product so these articles could not be classifies like the main ones.

I need to make a matrix visual like that: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM5IE.png)

But now I get this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M9U2.png)

How can I make a matrix visualization like that?

Thanks in advance,

Michael